# Rails: List of Gems being used by a particular application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, rubygems

There are many gems installed our development machines, and we not sure which gems are actually being used by the application. This list is not maintained in `environment.rb` either. Is there a way to figure our which gems are being used by a particular application?

**[EDIT]:**
Is it a safe way to find `require` in all `.rb` files and check in search result which gems are used in application?

Thanks,
Imran

Comment: just delete them all from `environment.rb` and try to start app it'll complain about missing gems

Comment: @Bohdan, I think it'll complain about first missing gem and break. This way I need to install them one by one. This could be the last option we can go for. Is there any script, gem etc to list the dependent gems -- in automated way?

Comment: Are you in rails 2 or 3?

Comment: ah, sorry, I've no idea then...

Answer (score 1):

You could try the standard rake tasks `rake gems` (should list the gems that this rails application depends on) or `rake gems:unpack` (should unpack all required gems into vendor/gems).

Comment: `rake gems` only lists the gems which are in `environment.rb` not all required by the application.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of, this is a motivator for folks to use bundler and rvm as this can be very painful if you've adopted a project that someone else wrote.

Comment: Okay, I am thinking to go for the `bunlder`. But the question is how can I cleanly identify the gems my application depends on so that I can configure them with `bundler`?